# stream_socket_enable_crypto(): Unable to locate certificate CN

Tags: php, laravel, ssl

I installed laravel 5.3 with php 5.6 on my local server and every time I try to send an email I get the error.

```
stream_socket_enable_crypto(): Unable to locate certificate CN
```

My mail settings for Laravel:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_PORT=587
 MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

From the research I have done I think it has something to do with a PHP setting but I am having difficulty finding what steps I need to take to resolve this. The email server is using a self signed cert so I wonder if there is a setting I need to set to allow self sign certs.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you